# Can't recover correct Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (OU) parameters from simulated data (R)

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, simulation

I'm trying to estimate the parameters of a discretized time series that I think may be described by an OU process.

To do so, I am using the methodology described here: https://www.sitmo.com/?p=134

Specifically, I am using least squares to regress the n-th term of the time-series against the (n-1)-th term, and am using the regression coefficients to estimate the parameters.

However, I find that I am not able to recover the parameters I simulate from. Here is my code for simulation:

```
ornstein_uhlenbeck <- function(T,n,nu,lambda,sigma,x0){
  dw  <- rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(T/n))
  dt  <- T/n
  x <- c(x0)
  for (i in 2:(n+1)) {
    x[i]  <-  x[i-1] + lambda*(nu-x[i-1])*dt + sigma*dw[i-1]
  }
  return(x);
}
```

This is the same code used [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/r-code-for-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process).

Here is my code to estimate from the simulated data

```
ss = matrix(0, 500, 3)
for (k in 1:500){
  nn1 = 500
  d = ornstein_uhlenbeck(TT, nn1, 0, 1, 1, x0) #theta = 0, kappa = 0, sigma = 0
  cal_ou = lm(d[2:(length(d)+1)] ~ d[1:(length(d))])
  coefs = summary(cal_ou)$coefficients
  theta_cand = coefs[1] / (1 - coefs[2])
  kappa_cand = - log(coefs[2]) / (TT/nn1)
  B2 = summary(cal_ou)$sigma
  sigma_cand = sqrt(2*kappa_cand/ (1 - exp(-2*kappa_cand*del_t)))*B2
  ss[k,] = c(theta_cand, kappa_cand, sigma_cand)
}
theta_est = mean(ss[,1])
kappa_est = mean(ss[,2])
sigma_est = mean(ss[,3])
kappa_sd = sd(ss[,2])/sqrt(500)
theta_sd = sd(ss[,1])/sqrt(500)
sigma_sd = sd(ss[,3])/sqrt(500)
```

And these are typical values I get for the estimates:

```
> theta_est
[1] 0.006430432
> kappa_est
[1] 1.583136
> sigma_est
[1] 1.010019
```

The estimates for theta and sigma are fine (long-run mean and volatility, respectively). However, the estimate for kappa is quite far away from what I specified.

I'm not sure what the issue is here, and why I can't recover the correct kappa value. Can anyone help?

Comment: What value do you use for `TT` (the length of the time interval)?  Although the least squares estimate of $a$ is unbiased, it is not true that $\hat\lambda=-\ln\hat a/\delta$ is unbiased for $\lambda=-\ln a/\delta$.

Comment: Also, your simulation algorithm is only an approximation valid for small `dt`.  You can do exact simulations using the recursion equation in the first document you link to.

Comment: I use TT such that my dt steps are 1/12 (ultimately, I'm calibrating to monthly data). 

And yes, in hindsight, it would make more sense to simulate from the exact solution of the SDE. Thank you for your help!